# RegEx match case sensitivity

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have this code >

```
Dim match = Regex.Match(text.ToLower(), "(?<=[get|post])\s(?<Path>/.*)\shttp/1\.1.*?host:\s(?<Host>[A-Za-z0-9\-\.]*)", RegexOptions.Singleline )
```

so when I do match it gave me the url all lower case

so I delete (ToLower) command but it didn't match when I delete it !!!!

could you give me like this Regex code so when I delete (ToLower) command it match .??

Comment: Just use the RegexOptions.IgnoreCase along side your Singleline option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor provides a method for this:

```
public Regex(string pattern,RegexOptions options)
```

With one of the items in `RegexOptions`:

```
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
```

---

You already use one `RegexOptions`, but `RegexOptions` is a `[Flags]` enum: you can use several options at once by using the bitwise or operator (`|`):

```
Dim match = Regex.Match(text, "<pattern>", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase )
```

---

The advantage is that the case is evaluated in the regex. A `ToLower` command would run over the string. For long strings, this would mean the code runs twice the time.

Comment: I maed it like this  
Dim match = Regex.Match(text, "(?<=[get|post])\s(?<Path>/.*)\shttp/1\.1.*?host:\s(?<Host>[A-Za-z0-9\-\.]*)", RegexOptions.Singleline And RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

and still no match

Comment: Why would the code run in twice the time?

Comment: @user3793707: You can do this with a bitwise or (updated answer).

Comment: @KyleW: What I mean is that `ToLower` runs in linear time on the string and `Regex` runs in linear time as well. The time complexity doesn't change. But the `ToLower` is in fact redundant since you can compile a regex that ignore the case at each character in the string.

Comment: Thank you very much  ... it works with OR instate of AND

Comment: @user3793707: Well `[Flag]` enums are represented using bitvectors. That means that item1 has a binary value of `0001` and item2 a value of `0010`. By using a bitwise or, the value is `0011` (one and two). Using a bitwise and, the value is `0000` (none).